# vsftpd on Ubuntu not obeying filesystem permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I'm trying to set an FTP upload to a web root on Ubuntu 12.04 using vsftp.
The user has a local account, username_ftp. I changed their home to their web root in /etc/passwd.

```
username_ftp:x:1004:1004:Users FTP Account,,,:/var/www/html/username:/bin/false
```

I am able to log in to the FTP server as this user, but I am unable to write.
The permissions on the directory are as follows:

```
ls -lha /var/www/html/username/
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 username_ftp username_ftp 4.0K Jan  9 10:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root       root       4.0K Jan  7 20:38 ..
```

Any ideas why I am unable to upload files when logged in as this user?
I believe I have all the necessary configuration options to allow writing from local users as filesystem permissions should allow.

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_users=NO
```

Comment: What does the vsftpd log say when trying to write/upload a file?

Comment: Oops, looks like it is a firewall issue. I am only getting this error when FTPing from inside the network. Outside it works fine.